# SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character WITH ()

Tags: python

I am getting this error with this command-

```
output_file_1_ = subprocess.run("awk -F "\t" '{ if(($3 >= 60) && ($13 >= 75) && ($11 <= 1e-5)) { print } }' output_file_1 |sort  -nr -k12| tail", capture_output=True, test=True, input=output_file_1)
```

```
File "./find_orthologs.py", line 68
    output_file_1_ = subprocess.run("awk -F "\t" '{ if(($3 >= 60) && ($13 >= 75) && ($11 <= 1e-5)) { print } }' output_file_1 |sort  -nr -k12| tail", capture_output=True, test=True, input=output_file_1)
                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Comment: Please Give A Minimal Reproducible Example Like Code Snippets So That We Can Help You On The Issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You have double quotes inside your double-quoted string. Either escape them or use single quotes.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).